# XMPP server connection for javascript code for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

How to make chat application, using XMPP server in PhoneGap. I dont khow to how to make `BOSH_SERVICE` url for XMPP connection, please give me sample working demo about chat app for PhoneGap code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Candy.JS an out of the box chat client which makes use of the Strophe.js Library:

http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/

It's actually very easy to put your own client together using Strophe alone but I would recommend learning by example and giving candy a once over.